# Creating dynamic header links in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

In my code i have an if statement, which is return is true, it would header the user to a specific page. But i want to send some data to the next page. So i tried using dynamic links. but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code;

```
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($query);

if($row->Usertype = "General_User")
{
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/GeneralUserHome.php?cid= echo $row->Company_ID");
}
else
{
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com');
}
?>
```

but when i'm redirected to the page, i get this;
http://www.mywebsite.com/GeneralUserHome.php?cid=%20echo%20'';

any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have `echo` in there?

Comment: you cannot embed PHP code inside php code like that. `<?php echo "<?php echo 'foo' ?>"; ?>` will echo php code, not 'foo'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have `echo` in there?

```
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/GeneralUserHome.php?cid={$row->Company_ID}");
```

Comment: this actually pointed me in the right direction, but, my variable data wont show in the link somehow... somehow it's empty

Comment: `print_r($row);` to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: okay, it's always returning a value of 1, even though the Company_ID= 2

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
if($row->Usertype = "General_User")
```

That's an assignment, and will always be true.  You want double-equals for comparison:

```
if($row->Usertype == "General_User")
```

As a note, I reverse the two in order to avoid these typos.  This will error out and tell you exactly what was wrong, if you typo'd a single equals sign:

```
if("General_User" = $row->Usertype)
```

Comment: I initially had the "==" but somehow, it only works when i use "=". Really weird...